# Evaluating $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n{n\choose i}2^i$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I'm being asked to "evaluate the sum"

$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^n{n\choose i}2^i$$

Writing out the first few values of $n$ it is clear that the sum is equal to $3^n$, however I'm not sure how to prove this. I know that it is straight forward to show that $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n{n\choose i}=2^n$, we just set $x=y=1$ in the binomial formula, but the $2^i$ seems to make things much less obvious.

The wording of the question seems ambiguous. I'm not sure if "evaluate" means that I don't need to prove the result? But just evaluating a few values of $n$ and calling it a day seems insufficient.

If anybody could give me a hint to maybe set me on the right track that would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Evaluating" = probably giving it a closed form of some sort. I wouldn't say that giving a couple of terms and writing that they are equal to $3^n$ is a legitimate proof.

Comment: Giving a couple terms and writing that the answer is $3^n$ definitely isn't a legitimate proof. I'm just not sure if I'm being asked for a legitimate proof or not.

Comment: @Gteal: It’s pretty safe to assume that you are being asked to justify (i.e., prove) your answer. By the way, while the use of the binomial theorem as in **APCorreia**’s answer is the way to go, you could also prove by induction on $n$ that the sum is $3^n$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott That was my back-up plan but I think I would need to use Pascal's identity right? (which hasn't been introduced yet in the text)

Comment: @Gteal: Yes, you would (or at least it’s the natural way to go).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Rewrite the given expression as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^{n}{n\choose i}2^{i} = \sum_{i=0}^{n}{n\choose i}2^{i}1^{n-i}
\end{align*}

and apply the binomial theorem.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Ah-hah! Thank you, I can take it from here I think. Just to make sure - your changing of the starting index wasn't needed was it?

Comment: @Gteal: The change in starting index is simply wrong: it changes the sum by $\binom{n}02^0=1$.

Comment: @Gteal It was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out. Henry has already fixed it anyway.